# I'm getting an error "Consumer closed input channel" ES 1.1

Tags: android, runtime-error, opengl-es-1.1

I'm stumped on this error:

```
.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or 
an error occurred.  events=0x8
```

The project compiles and begins to run, I looked at other people having this error and it seems to happen sometimes when your drawing is out of acceptable bounds, but I can't find any errors in my code.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

class Square {
public Square()
{
    float vertices[] =
    {
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f
    };

    byte maxColor = (byte)255;

    byte colors[] =
    {
        maxColor,        maxColor,       0,maxColor,
        0,       maxColor,maxColor,maxColor,
        0,              0,       0,maxColor,
        maxColor,       0,maxColor,maxColor,

        maxColor,       0,       0,maxColor,
        0,       maxColor,       0,maxColor,
        0,              0,maxColor,maxColor,
        0,              0,       0,maxColor,

    };

    //byte indices[] =
    //{
    //  0, 3, 1,
    //  0, 2, 3
    //};

    byte tfan1[] =
    {
        1,0,3,
        1,3,2,
        1,2,6,
        1,6,5,
        1,5,4,
        1,4,0
    };

    byte tfan2[] =
    {
        7,4,5,
        7,5,6,
        7,6,2,
        7,2,3,
        7,3,0,
        7,0,4
    };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);

    mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
    mColorBuffer.put(colors);
    mColorBuffer.position(0);

    mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan1.length);
    mIndexBuffer.put(tfan1);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);

    mTfan2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan2.length);
    mTfan2.put(tfan2);
    mTfan2.position(0);
}


public void draw(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glVertexPointer(3,  GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
    gl.glColorPointer(4,  GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6*3, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan1);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6*3, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan2);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);
}

private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mColorBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mIndexBuffer;
private ByteBuffer mTfan1;
private ByteBuffer mTfan2;

}
```

Then this code:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import java.lang.Math;

public class SquareRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
public SquareRenderer(boolean useTranslucentBackground)
{
    mTranslucentBackground = useTranslucentBackground;
    mSquare = new Square();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glRotatef(mAngle,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(mAngle,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f,(float)Math.sin(mTransY), -7.0f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    mSquare.draw(gl);

    mTransY += 0.075f;
    mAngle +=  0.4;

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
{
    gl.glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    float aspectRatio;
    float zNear = 0.1f;
    float zFar = 1000;
    float fieldOfView = 30.0f/57.3f;
    float size;

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);

    aspectRatio = (float)width/(float)height;
    // float ratio = (float) width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);

    size = zNear * (float)(Math.tan((double)(fieldOfView/2.0f)));

    gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / aspectRatio, size / aspectRatio, zNear, zFar);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    // gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1,1,1,10);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
{
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);

    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

    if (mTranslucentBackground)
    {
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

private boolean mTranslucentBackground;
private Square mSquare;
private float mTransY;
private float mAngle;
}
```

And to display it I use this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    view.setRenderer(new SquareRenderer(true));
    setContentView(view);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error after it:  .MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: I never ended up finding the solution to this particular problem, but I did end up re-writing the code and it works well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was happening because I was closing the emulator, or it wasn't starting before the program was running.